# Remove rows with specific NA column

Tags: r, na

I have the Following dataset where some entries (unique A) Don't have data in B and others that have sometimes.

```
A B
1 NA
2 NA
3 77
1 NA
2 81
```

I want to delete the entries that **Always have NA** and keep the rest

```
A B
2 NA
3 77
2 81
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `ave` grouped by `A` and remove the groups that has `all` `NA`s

```
df[!with(df, ave(is.na(B), A, FUN = all)), ]

#  A  B
#2 2 NA
#3 3 77
#5 2 81
```

---

Using the same logic with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(A) %>%
   filter(!all(is.na(B)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, for each group defined by `A` we return TRUE if any of its elements in `B` are not `NA`.

```
subset(DF, ave(!is.na(B), A, FUN = any))
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
A B
1 NA
2 NA
3 77
1 NA
2 81"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .SD[any(!is.na(B))], A]
#    A  B
#1: 2 NA
#2: 2 81
#3: 3 77
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), B = c(NA, NA, 77L, 
  NA, 81L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```